# Python - Reactivating my virtualenv for django project

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, terminal, virtualenv

(Beginner) I am working with a virtualenv for a django project using my Macos terminal and Visual Studio Code.

Recently, my terminal disappeared where I was running all of my code and I do not know how to reenter my virtualenv or my project that I still have on Visual Studio Code. I have tried everything including:

```
source virtualenv/bin/activate
```

Or,

```
virtualenv/source/activate
```

Or,

```
cd my_project_name
```

and then trying to enter my virtualenv following this step (^) with the commands above.

Nothing is working and when I run "python manage.py runserver" it says there is no such file or directory. I am struggling and do not know how to continue my current project on django before getting back to my project and virtualenv.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where did you create your virtual environment? `source virtualenv/bin/activate` will only work if you are one directory above the `virtualenv` directory. Check that you are providing the correct path to where the virtual environment is saved. In general, to activate the virtual environment from anywhere in the filesystem, you'd do `source relative/path/to/directory/virtualenv/source/activate`.

Comment: I know that I created my django project on my desktop but I am unsure how to find where I originally created the virtual environment. I followed a tutorial where I did {pip install virtualenv} and then forgot which directory it was saved in (using mkdir) before creating the name, it might be the desktop but I am unsure unfortunately.

Comment: Could you try running `find /Users -path "*/virtualenv/bin/activate"` to find where you've saved your venv? This might take some time as it'll scan the entirety of the `Users` directory. Once you've found it, you can `source` the `activate` file by providing the relative path to it.

Comment: Alternatively, for good measure, also check if you've created the venv in your home directory (`/Users/<username>` for Mac) to save you the trouble of running `find`.

Comment: I tried running the find command and I accidentally didn't allow the terminal to access my photos, calendars, reminders, etc. but allowed it to access other files but it all turned out to be "Operation not permitted". Unfortunately, the  (/Users/<username>) did not find anything either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio code actually has a convenient way of keeping track of virtual environments. At the very bottom in the blue footer bar, click next to the refresh icon, and you should see whether it's available.

If it's really gone, don't sweat it. Virtual environments are completely expendable – it'll turn up. For now, just make another, and be sure you create it in your project's root directory this time.

You actually usually don't need to activate a venv with vscode. Just `cd` into the project root directory and open vscode with `code .`. The activated envionment will appear in that same spot in the footer.

Also, look into using a `requirements.txt` file, it'll save a lot of time if you keep misplacing the virtualenv.

And finally, it's best not to name your venv "virtualenv", name it something unique – otherwise it's guaranteed to confuse!

Comment: Thanks so much John! For some reason I don't see the refresh icon in the blue footer so I assume it's not there.. I'll have to make a new virtualenv I assume but would you be able to please explain how I can ensure this new one will be in my project's root directory?

Comment: Simple – just `cd` into that directory. Then the create the virtualenv (`virtualenv my_venv`)

Comment: Thanks John! I was able to create a new virtualenv in the same directory (hopefully). I'm now wondering how to access the same django file with this new directory without having to create a new project/app since I have existing ones already with code. The idea is to run `python manage.py runserver` and the existing django project will load in my browser. Any tips to achieve this? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The whole point of a virtualenv is that you isolate your python libraries. It's just a case of reinstalling django in the virtualenv you just created. Activate the venv in vscode or with `source my_venv/bin/activate`, then `pip install django`. Also install any other libraries you need. And google how to use a `requirements.txt` file, to save you doing this again if you need to make a new virtualenv in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows kindly follow the given steps to CREATE VIRTUAL ENVIRNMENT
So basically there are 4 steps involved in this:

a) Opening CMD

b) Navigating to the destination where you want to create your Django Project

c) Creating & Activating your virtual env

d) Checking if virtual env is enabled

1. Open CMD (Press Windows key + R) then a Pop-up will appear inside it type - CMD.
   CMD containing a black screen is now open.
2. Now navigate to folder where you want to create your django project using "cd"
   command
3. Once a folder is created (mkdir Folder_name), go inside the folder using cd 7
   type following command
4. python -m venv Environment_Name
5. cd Environment_Name
6. cd Scripts
7. activate
8. cd ..
9. cls ( to clear the screen)

To check if virtual environment is enabled or not:

1. We are still in Virtual Environment type following commands by
   downloading django in VE & checking it's version
2. pip install django
3. import django
4. django .**version** ((Double underscore before & after version it's now
   showing here))

Now to Create our First Application inside VE type the following commands:

1. django-admin startproject Project_NAME_of_your_choice
   (a folder with above name will be created inside VE)
2. code . (This will open VS_Code)

To reconnect to virtual environment once PC goes switch off

1. Open CMD & navigate folder using "cd" command-
   Folder_Created_for_Django_Project -> (inside it is VE folder) -> Go inside that VE folder & type the following commands -

Same as above point 5,6 & 7

4. cd Environment_Name
5. cd Scripts
6. activate
7. cd ..

You are re-connected to Virtual Environment..