# "module not found" python virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have a script like this:

```
#import statements 
from package1 import *

#code
```

I made a virtual environment and installed package1 like this:

```
(base) user:~ user$ cd ./Project_Folder
(base) user:~ user$ virtualenv venv 
#activate the virtual environment 
(base) user:~ user$ source venv/bin/activate
# Install the package locally
(venv) (base) user:~ user$  pip install -U package1
# Check what packages are now installed locally
(venv) (base) user:~ user$ pip list
```

package1 is on this list, but when I try running the code from within Visual Studios, I get a "ModuleNotFoundError": ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'

However, when I install package1 from terminal normally (i.e from base and not venv), it successfully runs in VS:

```
(base) user:~ user$ pip install package1
```

why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

my directory tree looks like this. Note that package1 is in env/lib/python3.8.

```
 ./Project_Folder

|— myScript.ipynb
|— data
|— images 
|__ …
|__ venv
    |— bin
    |— lib
    |   |__python3.8
    |       |__site-packages
    |           |— package1
    |           |— package2
    |           |_ package3
    |__ pyvenv.cfg
```

I have tried implementing solutions in similar  stackoverflow posts, but I haven't had any success.

System Specs:
System Version: macOS Catalina 10.15.7
Python Version: 3.7.6

thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the name of the actual package your trying to install, instead of simply calling it "package1".

Comment: it's called music21

Comment: You need to activating your virtualenv in VSCode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67274639/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code+virtualenv

Comment: I followed the steps in the linked posts, but it still is not working for me. when following link1, the command "code ." I get bash: --code command not found", and when following link2,  in the json settings file, there is no line containing "Python.path:"